# Не могу обратиться к файлам на сервере если папка на русском языке

Tags: веб-сервер

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему я не могу обратиться к файлам на сервере если папки на русском языке?

Если же папка на анг все норм.

Comment: А зачем вы используете в именах папок/файлов русские буквы? Используйте латинские буквы и все будет ок. P.S. Обратиться же не можете к файлам вероятнее всего по причине несовпадения кодировок используемых для именования на сервере и в вашем запросе.

Comment: Если не сложно опишите как возникла такая ситуация? Это произошло после какого-то события?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.